# JQuery parent id selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a markup like this

```
<div id="cat1" class="category">
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    //some more elements
</div>
<div id="cat2" class="category">
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    //some more elements
</div>
<div id="cat3" class="category">
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    //some more elements
</div>
```

And I am trying to get the id of the parent divs when a user clicks on any item inside that div. Inner elements may or may not have ids and classes.

I am trying to achieve this by jquery but don't know how to select the parent id. My attempt with jquery so far is this,

```
$(".category").click(function () {
    window.alert($(this).id);
});
```

but it gives me unknown id when I click on something inside the category div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `alert(this.id);`

Comment: $('.category').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id')
)})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$().attr`    to fetch ID

```
 $(".category").on('click', function(e){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
 })
```